# mod_rewrite - how do I fail a rule if a header doesn't exist?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have the following Rewrite statement:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_SOMEHEADER} ^mystring$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.222\.111\.222$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /mypage.html     [L]
```

The way I read this is:

```
IF HTTP_X_SOMEHEADER equals "mystring" 
AND  
REMOTE_ADDR equals 111.222.111.222 
THEN  
GOTO mypage.html
```

However what I'm seeing is that if the IP is 111.222.111.222 but HTTP-X-SOMEHEADER doesn't exist then the rule passes.

I'd like the rule to only pass if the header HTTP-X-SOMEHEADER exists and the IP is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by the rule passes? You mean if someone doesn't have the header they get redirected to mypage.html anyways?

Comment: Hi Phil, that's correct.  Just the IP needs to match and the redirect happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need `RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_X_SOMEHEADER}` to pick up an arbitrary HTTP header that's not in the list given in the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Your code matches the behaviour I would expect from the setup, so there's more going on.  What's in the error log?

Comment: (OK, I've added the %{HTTP:...}

I think I see what's happening.  I have multiple RewriteCond and RewriteRule groupings and more than one of them has the RewriteRule of (.*)

I think it's finding the first (.*) RewriteRule and is then checking the RewriteCond's associated with it.

Basically what I'm trying to do is set up multiple RewriteCond and RewriteRule blocks that allow things through if a certain criteria is met.  This means I have more than one (.*) RewriteRule.  Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Post the whole lot if you want, and we can go from there.  Ideally, you want the most restrictive rule first on the list.

Comment: CK, thanks very much.  Changing the order of my rules (plus noticing an error in my regexp) fixed the problem.  The above rule group is now being picked up correctly.